# Is there a way to programmatically find the number of default values or skip all default values of a formGroup in Angular?

Tags: angular, observable, angular-reactive-forms, onchange, formgroups

I have a formGroup that has some default values, i.e. non null. I want to react to changes in this formGroup so I use `this.FG.valueChanges.subscribe()`. The problem is, this method also detects default values and interprets them as changes. In order to circumvent this undesired behavior, I do the following:

```
this.FG.valueChanges.pipe(
      startWith(1),
      distinctUntilChanged(),
      skip(8) // hardcoded
  ).subscribe(v => console.log(`new value: ${v}`));
```

The problem is that the "8" you can see there is hard-coded. It represents the number of default values in the form group `FG`.

Is there a way to programatically find the number of default values or skip all default values in order to subscribe only to the new values that reflect a user interaction?

EDIT:

Here's a fragment that shows how default values are added:

```
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.FG = new FormGroup({
      minSaveFG: new FormGroup({
        currentMeasure: new FormControl({value: null, disabled: !this.editable}, Validators.required)
      }),
      currentStartDate: new FormControl({value: this.calendarInfo.startDate ? this.calendarInfo.startDate : this.initialStartDate,
        disabled: !this.editable && !this.correctionMode}, Validators.required),
```

The subscribe is called after the initialization.

Comment: How do you assign the default values? Do you have something like `{ control: this.fb.control(defaultValue) }` or do you assign the default values after you subscribe?

Comment: I think you should you `filter` operator to filter out stream with valid values

Comment: why not subscribe **after** you give the default values? Another approach can be skip(this.FG.controls.length), but I'm not prety sure about this last idea

Comment: I added info how default values are assigned. And I subscribe in ngInit after the initialization

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me you are getting these values async and assigning them later, because I don't see it firing when the form is initially built. Whatever the issue is, the solution is to use `emitEvent: false`, which does not make the `valueChanges` fire:

```ts
this.myForm = this.fb.group({
  input1: ["hello", { emitEvent: false }]
});
```

The same can be applied if you use `setValue` or `patchValue` as well, or any of the methods that somehow manipulates the form, for example:

```ts
this.myForm.get('input1').setValue('hello2', { emitEvent: false})
```

PS. Remember to unsubscribe `valueChanges` when component is destroyed!

Comment: I edited my original post in order to show how default values are added.

Comment: Yes, so did you try my solution? Also I like to use formbuilder. The issue could also be if you have initialized `FG` as `new FormGroup` and in the `OnInit` you are again calling `new FormGroup`, that would surely trigger valuechanges if you are calling it twice. (this is just a guess as I have no idea if you have even initialized it)